# Is it possible to call a mehod as a variable?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a class: class1
It has multiple methods: method1, method2,...

is is possible to define a variable like: var = method1
to call this method from an instance of class1 ?

Meaning, instead of doing this:

```
instance1 = class1

result = instance1.method1
```

I want to do something like this:

```
instance1 = class1
var = method1

result = instance1.var
```

Is this somehow possible in python?

Many thanks upfront

I tried exactly like this:

```
instance1 = class1
var = method1

result = instance1.var
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you are just missing the parentheses, `()`:

```
class Class1:
    def method1(self):
        return "Method1 called"

instance1 = Class1()
var = instance1.method1
result = var()
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
Method1 called
```

Comment: Sometime, it can be so easy. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Python's built-in getattr() function. getattr() allows you to access an object's attribute (including methods) using a string that contains the attribute's name. Here is an example.

```
class class1:

    def method1(self):
        return "This is method1's result"

    def method2(self):
        return "This is method2's result"

instance1 = class1()

var = "method1"
result = getattr(instance1, var)()

print(result)  # Output: This is method1's result
```

Keep in mind that this can make your code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You were not far, but you have to *scope* the variable inside the `class1` class, because `method1` only makes sense there:

Example:

```
class class1:
    def method1(self):
        print('method1 called on', str(class1), id(self))
```

You can test it that way:

```
instance1 = class1()
print(id(instance1))    # gives for example 1565329136688

class1.var = class1.method1
instance1.var()
```

would display:

```
method1 called on <class '__main__.class1'> 1565329136688
```